# C++ fastest string lower case and find

Tags: c++

I have a vector of strings loaded from a file via `ifstream`, it does not need to be a vector but it looks like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> data;
data.push_back("CONSISTENTTEXT:variabletext1");
data.push_back("CONSISTENTTEXT:variabletext2");
// 100,000 + more push_back's
```

As it's a large vector and I need to loop through to find all references of a search string I'm wondering how to do the most efficient string case insensitive find given I can ignore the first 15 characters of the string?

Comment: Take a look http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index

Comment: If you're doing a number of searches, it sounds like you're using the wrong container for the job.  The best you'll get with an unsorted vector is O(N).  You want to either sort your vector first or pick another container.  Aside:  Why store "CONSISTENTTEXT: " at all, just remove it and add it as required and make your problem easier

Comment: Do you know the total number of elements? If yes try to use std::array instead of std::vector, else I would call reserve() on std::vector to try to minimize the number of reallocations under the hood

Comment: @OnurA. A `std::array` is not going to make a difference here. You'd still have to dynamically allocate it (`std::unique_ptr<std::array<std::string, N>>`), so the only memory savings would be a couple pointers

Comment: @Justin Can you elaborate `You'd still have to dynamically allocate it
 (std::unique_ptr<std::array<std::string, N>>)` ? Why he needs to dynamically allocate via unique_ptr if he already knew the size?

Comment: @OnurA 100000+ `std::string`s are not going to fit on the stack

Comment: @Justin it depends on parameters like OS, memory etc. He can also change stack size on some systems

Comment: @OnurA true, but it's still not a good idea to allocate that much on the stack. Also, a single 2 mb allocation really doesn't take much time. The allocation is not going to be the bottleneck, as you need the memory anyway.

Comment: @Justin of course! Btw, nevertheless, since the OP is gonna make searching on it, another container like std::set, std::map or if he has access to Modern C++, std::unordered_set or std::unordered_map would be better fit for this.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to try is just the obvious:

```
std::copy_if(data.begin(), data.end(), output,
    [&searchForMe](std::string const& str) {
        return caseInsensitiveEquals(
            std::string_view{str}.remove_prefix(15),
            std::string_view{searchForMe}.remove_prefix(15));
    });
```

<sup>See [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and [`std::string_view::remove_prefix`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/remove_prefix)</sup>

You'd also probably just want to remove the prefixes before you even add it to `data`. This would be a significant reduction in your memory usage and could potentially make your strings fit within the small-string-optimization size. Searching would then be really easy:

```
std::copy_if(data.begin(), data.end(), output,
    [&searchForMe](std::string const& str) { // maybe `std::string_view str`
        return caseInsensitiveEquals(str, searchForMe);
    });
```

If this is not fast enough (likely it is not fast enough as your vector is large), there are some options. You could always reach for the [Execution Policies](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t), but they don't help reduce the amount of work that needs to be done.

The next thing I would consider is `std::equal_range`, which would require sorting the data:

```
// assuming you removed all the prefixes
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), caseInsensitiveLessThan);
auto rangePair = std::equal_range(data.begin(), data.end(), searchForMe, caseInsensitiveLessThan);
```

After the `O(n log n)` sort, the lookup is `O(log n)`.

If this is still not fast enough, or you perhaps cannot pay for a sort, you need a specialized data structure. You might be able to get away with a [`std::unordered_multiset<std::string, CaseInsensitiveHash, CaseInsensitiveEquals>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset).